# How to get a free lab session using this database-schema?

Tags: database, scheduling

Hey all, thanks in advance for reading!

The problem is to try and find a time in which an instructor is free, a lab is free and the students enrolled in a class are free. There is only one instructor, around 6 lab rooms, and an average of 20 students.

Lab rooms, instructors and students have already times at which they are busy/occupied.
Time is split into 1.5 hour blocks starting from 8-930, 930-1100 all the ways to 330-500.
There are 5 days to consider, Monday - Friday.
If there is not a single block that can fit all students,instructor and lab then the class can be split into sessions.

Here is what i was thinking of as a database and inputs/outputs:

Database:

```
Table :  Lab
Fields : l_id, l_name, l_capacity, BM893, BM9311, BM11123, BM1232, BM233, BM335, BT893, BT9311, BT11123, BT1232, BT233, BT335, BW893, BW9311, BW11123, BW1232, BW233, BW335, BTH893, BTH9311, BTH11123, BTH1232, BTH233, BTH335, BF893, BF9311, BF11123, BF1232, BF233, BF335
(each field representing a block to time for a day… e.g.  BM893 is Block Monday 8 – 930, all fields are integers where 0 is free and 1 is occupied/busy)

Table: Student
Fields :s_id, s_name, BM893, BM9311, BM11123, BM1232, BM233, BM335, BT893, BT9311, BT11123, BT1232, BT233, BT335, BW893, BW9311, BW11123, BW1232, BW233, BW335, BTH893, BTH9311, BTH11123, BTH1232, BTH233, BTH335, BF893, BF9311, BF11123, BF1232, BF233, BF335
(each field representing a block to time for a day… e.g.  BM893 is Block Monday 8 – 930, all fields are integers where 0 is free and 1 is occupied/busy)

Table: Instructor
Fields : i_id, i_name, BM893, BM9311, BM11123, BM1232, BM233, BM335, BT893, BT9311, BT11123, BT1232, BT233, BT335, BW893, BW9311, BW11123, BW1232, BW233, BW335, BTH893, BTH9311, BTH11123, BTH1232, BTH233, BTH335, BF893, BF9311, BF11123, BF1232, BF233, BF335
(each field representing a block to time for a day… e.g.  BM893 is Block Monday 8 – 930, all fields are integers where 0 is free and 1 is occupied/busy)
```

Input:

```
1 instructor (i_id)
All labs
N students (s_id, s_id…etc)
```

Output:

> Time block for session (if more than
>   one section than also s_id of every
>   student in each section)

Could someone please help me with the algorithm?

Thank You very much

Comment: I removed the algorithm tag. This looks more like a database design/query problem.

Comment: Its my BS graduation project, query? i know we just pretty much search for a free time, but its when we have o split into sections thats a problem, dont u think that needs an algorithm to take into account the permutations of how you may distribute the students? and into which labs concidering capacity where being free is not enough

Answer (score 0):

I would have one table for day of week with 5 rows, M-F

another table with time of day and start times, however many you have (0800, 0930,... 1530)

another table (or query/view) with the cartesian product of days and times

another table with lab details (building, room number, whatever)

another table with student details (student id, first name, last name)

another table with instructor details (instructor id, name, department)

then you have your busy/occupied/unavailable table, with itemType (lab or student or instructor,) day busy (m-f), and time busy (0800-1530).  you don't need to store free times because they can be derived from the cartesian product table with all day and time sets.

then you're all set- you have all the data stored you need and can see if there are any rows in the set of all days and times which don't have corresponding rows in the busy table.

Comment: hey thx for the swift response... but thats pretty much the easy part which i had no problem with. The problem is with when there is not a single time that is feasible and we must thus split into 2 sections, how can the algorithm take into concideration permutations of how each section may be filled with students?

Comment: if there's no open time for everyone and there's a decision to split the class, then you have 2 classes to work with and fewer students.  should be easier to find times when all students are available.